# Auxiliary verb after interrogative

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I have a problem with auxiliary verbs in questions with interrogatives.
I can't feel the difference between following questions.
"What do tenses use in the essay?" or "What tenses use in the essay"?

Could you help me?

Comment: Neither sentence make sense. Perhaps you mean "what tenses *are used* in the essay?" It's unusual to say tenses use something, unless you specifically mean (for example) that some tenses use auxiliary verbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second one, i.e. "What tenses use in the essay?" is wrong. The first one is correct. It doesn't make sense without the auxiliary verb. Consider this - Who **are** you? You can't say "Who you?" Here, "are" is required to render the sentence complete. You can modify the second one as "Tell me **what tenses use in the essay**." Just like, you don't say "Where you live?" You say "Where **do** you live?" or "Tell me **where you live**." Also, "Tell me **who you are**." would make it correct.
https://learningenglish.voanews.com/a/forming-questions-part-1-subject-questions/4550920.html

You also can't say "Tell me where **do** you live." Although, you can use "Tell me, where do you live?", that is, it can be used but necessarily with a comma.
[Which is correct (if any): "please let me know what do you think"? or "please let me know what you think"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69684/which-is-correct-if-any-please-let-me-know-what-do-you-think-or-please-le)

Comment: "What do tenses use in the essay?" is also incorrect - neither of OP's choices is good. Something like "What tenses **are used** in the essay?" is better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how to frame questions. What exactly are you trying to say with your sentence?

Refer to the following articles:

http://englishisducksoup.com/grammar/using-what-where-when-why-who-and-how/

https://www.mmmenglish.com/2017/06/11/asking-questions-in-english-question-structure-fix-your-grammar-mistakes/